# Accessing a has_one associations' attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, has-one

I'm still quite new to Rails so hopefully this isn't a silly question.

I have two models: User and Chore. User has_one chore, and Chore belongs to User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :chore_done, :email, :name, :phone
  has_one :chore

class Chore < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
```

In my user index, I'm trying to show all users and display the chore that is associated with him or her. I'm doing this by passing User.all to the view and using a .each to iterate through each user:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.chore.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.chore_done? %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot access the name attribute of the Chore. I get this error:

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

If I remove the .name attribute, it just returns a pointer to the Chore object.

I have a feeling this has something to do with passing the User.all object to the view and then iterating over that. Just accessing a specific User object (e.g. User.find(1)) in the console, and then accessing user.chore.name works fine.

```
1.9.3-p194 :045 > user = User.find(4)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
 => #<User id: 4, name: "Example User", email: "example@dot.com", phone: 8675309, chore_done: false, created_at: "2012-11-05 01:53:33", updated_at: "2012-11-05 01:53:33"> 
1.9.3-p194 :046 > user.chore.name
  Chore Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "chores".* FROM "chores" WHERE "chores"."user_id" = 4 LIMIT 1
 => "Living room"
```

I read a bit about AssociationProxy in the APIDock, but I don't think I understand it completely nor do I know how to work with it. From what I gathered, accessing all objects in a model returns an Array of objects but doesn't return a complete set of attributes for its dependencies? So, in this case, I get a pointer to the Chore object but no access to any of its attributes.

I could certainly just add Chore as another column in my user table, but I may add to that model in the future + I just want to figure out how the has_one association works anyway.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

This says that you are trying to call some method `name()` on an an instance of `Nil`. Within your code's context, that says that `chore` on this line is `nil`

```
<td><%= user.chore.name %></td>
```

Simply put, one of the `User` instances in `@user` has no associated `Chore`. One simple way to accomodate this in your view is by checking if `user.chore` exists.

```
<td><%= user.chore.nil? ?  "some default name" : user.chore.name %></td>
```

Comment: Ah! That makes so much sense. I made this much more complicated than it was. Just breaking down what you've written ... I haven't seen this syntax (the second question mark) in rails before, but it seems very similar to SQL queries. Cool!

Comment: It's called a **ternary operator**. `(condition) ? "true case" : "false case"`

Comment: Stylish way to avoid ternaries with rails: `user.chore.try(:name)` http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Answer (score 5):

It's because not every user has a chore associated with it.

There are a few ways you can deal with this; I'm partial to the iteration pattern using `Array()` to coerce a collection. You can do this in your view:

```
<% Array(user.chore).each do |chore| %>
  <td><%= chore.name %></td>
  <td><%= chore.done? %></td>
<% end %>
```

`Array()` will instantiate an empty array if `chore` is nil, meaning nothing happens when you try to iterate over it. If a chore is present, it will iterate over `[chore]`.

The benefit of this pattern is that it doesn't violate [Tell don't ask](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27572137956/tell-dont-ask). Asking an object if it is `nil?` is also possible, but it's more of a procedural technique that doesn't take advantage of Ruby's strong object-oriented features.

**Edit**

As Deefour points out, this will result in a table with mismatched columns. You should probably use his solution for this case.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Sorry, I wan't paying attention to the rest of the table.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option that uses Rails' Delegate module:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :chore
  delegate :name, to: :chore, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

This will allow you to call `<%= user.chore_name %>`, which will pass the `name` call onto chore, returning `nil` if there is none.

Comment: `:allow_nil - if set to true, prevents a NoMethodError to be raised`

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
<td><%= user.chore.try(:name) %></td>
```

This will return `nil` if there is no `user.chore`.