# Rails - how to search the console where there is a has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to use associations in my views. There is something wrong where the association is a has_one relationship.

I have models called Project and Package. The associations are:

```
Project has_one :package

Package belongs_to :project
```

In the console, I can write:

```
p = Project.where(id: 26)
```

That gives me a project. Then I write:

```
p.package
```

I expect that to give me the associated package. Instead I get a long error message that starts with these lines:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `package' for #<Project::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb275c17698>
```

I don't know what this message means. I'm especially confused, because I can write:

```
p = Package.find_by(project_id:26)
```

That gives me the right package.

```
p = Package.find_by(project_id:26)
  Package Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "packages".* FROM "packages" WHERE "packages"."project_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["project_id", 26]]
 => #<Package id: 25, project_id: 26, created_at: "2016-08-18 23:16:06", updated_at: "2016-08-24 05:11:11", has_gallery: nil>
```

Why can't I find the package by writing p.package in the console?

I have seen  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225002/accessing-a-has-one-associations-attributes) but i haven't understood the gist of what's going on.

Comment: How did you call your foreign keys and in which table did you place them

Comment: @Chris - what do you mean? Project has an id and since package belongs to project, the package table has a project_id key in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` returns an array of related objects (usually used with `has_many` association). If there is only one associated object, it will still return it in an array.

`find_by` generates `LIMIT 1` at the end of the SQL query and returns only one instance.

You can't call `package` on an array, since an `ActiveRecord_Relation` array has no Idea about the associations. Only `Project` objects know the method `package`. This is why `Project.where(id: something).package` won't work but `Project.find_by(id: something).package` will.

If you want to call `package` when using `where`, you have to pick an object(like from any other array) - `Project.where(id: something).first.package` - this will call `package` on the first element of the array, which will work

Comment: Thanks. That did work to get the package, but then I want to see an attribute on the package table by doing: p.has_participants (has_participants is an attribute in the package table), but I get: p.has_participants
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_participants' for #<Project:0x007fe1751a0a78>
This is even though the previous p.package gives me a record that includes "false" as the answer to has_participants. How do I make sense of that?

Comment: @Mel can you please update the question with your view code? Because it is clear from the error that you are calling `has_participants` on a `Project` object.

Comment: @Mel no problem :)